# How to apply K-Medoids in PySpark?

Tags: python, clustering, apache-spark, pyspark

the pyspark ml library does not provide any clustering methods for K-Medoids. So my question is, how can one apply K-Medoids in a pyspark context?

Answer (score 0):

There is a k-medoids clustering for PySpark at [spark-packages.org/package/tdebatty/spark-kmedoids](https://spark-packages.org/package/tdebatty/spark-kmedoids) and the source code is [github.com/tdebatty/spark-kmedoids](https://github.com/tdebatty/spark-kmedoids).

It can be installed with:

```
> $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages tdebatty:spark-kmedoids:0.1.2
```

Comment: Hmm. There is no documentation and outdated gitrepo. Sure that it can handle Python?